# What is the difference between these 2 conditions of probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations, conditional-probability

What is the difference between the following statements:(or are they the same)

Statement 1: What is the probability of king of spades being the 10th card

Statement 2: What is the probability of the 10th card being the king of spades

(Considering the regular pack of 52 cards)

Comment: Why do you think there even is a difference?

Comment: This is an occurrence of the commutativity of the equality relation in natural language

Comment: If the statements were same (as mentioned in the comments) why are the results claimed by this book different. I am seriously confused.

Image source: Challenges and Thrills of Pre College Mathematics: By V Krishnamurthy
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIj5z.jpg

Comment: The numbers in your image... $\left(1-\frac{1}{52}\right)^9\times\frac{1}{52}$ correspond to if the dealing was done **with replacement**, that the first occurrence of a king of spades is the tenth time drawing from the deck, *where the result of each draw is independent of one another* (*i.e. after each draw is revealed, it is shuffled back into the deck and another random card (possibly the same) is revealed for the next draw*).  This is typically not what is meant when we say "*a deck of cards is dealt out*" which makes me think the book is simply wrong.

Comment: Under the typical meanings of the words in the question, both problems should have had an answer of $\frac{1}{52}$.

Comment: I would not be surprised if there are additional errors in the book related to multiplying probabilities that should not be multiplied.  Be warned that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ is true if *and only if* the events $A$ and $B$ are independent.  The results of draws from a deck without replacement are one of the most basic examples of non-independent events, and it is frankly embarrassing that a book could get this wrong.